# Start Glassfish App server on Debian

Tags: glassfish, debian

A simple question. I installed glasfish-javaee, glashfish-appserver etc. with apt-get on Debian 6.0. What I subsequent expected was that I could find 'asadmin' to start the server and if needed create a init.d script for automatic startup.

It might just be last, but I cannot find how to start the app server and cannot find asadmin... any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have installed just java libraries (which are in /usr/share/java) but not the actual Glassfish server.

You can follow for example this manual to install the server: http://debian-resources.org/node/132/

Comment: Thanks for that, I thought I was going insane, the package description could be a bit more descriptive.
The tutorial installs the stuff in /opt, this just makes me cringe! WTH do you have /usr/local for?!

Comment: The link is unfortunately broken.